# Is it possible for a method to determine if it's returned value will be used?

Tags: java, methods, return-value

For a method such as:

```
String x()
{
    return "x";
}
```

is it possible for it to test if it is being called in a void context. IE determine if it is being called like:

```
String ex = x();
```

or just like

```
x();
```

Comment: No, it's not. But if you try to explain why you would need to know, maybe there's a different solution.

Comment: @NilsH Yes, this smells a little like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, this is not something that Java supports.

But on the plus side, I can't think of a good reason why a method would need to know that. So all is well.

Comment: The only reason I could think of is to detect it as a bug. And you could maybe achieve that with a good code inspection tool like FindBug, Checkstyle etc.

Comment: @NilsH Perhaps. Although I would suspect unit testing would be a better approach.

Comment: Probably. But tools like FindBugs are useful in some cases. But now we're getting off topic... :)

Comment: The reason I wanted to test, was in an Android Library function I am writing, in some parts of the code it's not possible to return an error message to the user (eg from an onSomething method) so I launch an activity that displays an error message. This would only happen if the user does not test their calls properly. In other cases it is possible to return an error value. If what I had been asking about was possible, I could have made the code fall back to displaying an activity if the user was not accepting the returned error value.

Comment: The method could take an argument to indicate which action to take, but since it only comes into play if the user has not written their code correctly, I can't rely on the user passing the correct flag. I had been hoping that there was some way using generics with a return value of <T> Object or something. Never mind.

Comment: @user2202013 Can you edit your question to include these details?

Comment: @user2202013 That's a perfectly legal reasoning, and an interesting question. Please update your question with the new details, as DuncanJones suggests. But to answer it in advance, I would probably solve it with a "callback" parameter, ensuring that the user of your library had to supply this callback to use it.

Comment: I had considered a callback, but since the problems can only occur if the coder has made some basic errors I have decided to always just use an activity to display the error. In my case, even the most basic testing by the coder would pick this up.

Comment: I can think of another reason to want to test if a method is being called in a void context (which some programming languages do). This would be for efficiency reasons. The android Editor class has a commit() method and recent versions of android have an apply() method. They both do the same thing, but apply() does not go to the bother of finding out if the commit worked to return a Boolean to the user like commit(0 does. If commit() could detect a void context it could be the same as apply() when in a void context, and would be there on all android platforms (unlike apply)

Answer (score 1):

Method *is* a method. It accepts parameters, does some calculations and returns a value. That's it. Other code belongs to other methods.

Answer (score 0):

if gasoline can tell you vehicle that is going to use it then yes else no.

Anyways you can have a flag that is set(depending on your condition) before your method being called and in that way you can check if it is going to be used further.